# HTTP basic access denied when pushing folder to new project

Tags: git

I have same problem with any new project I try to work with:

I created new project in gitlab and tried to push folder (which does not have any git or `.git` files/folders) into it. (`git push`) but I got error:

```
remote: HTTP basic access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for...
```

I can clone the new project (which is empty) copy the files into and push them without any error.

I tried to push that command:

```
 git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

but same results.

More information:

- in the folder I run `git init` and `git remote add origin`

What is the error ?

How can I fix it (without cloning, copy files and pushing).

I want to be able to create new project and push existing folder
I'm getting the error just if I'm trying to push existing folder.

I'm working with `linux`

Comment: What are you using as a login with the git client - your gitlab account password? Do you need to use an access token (e.g. you have 2FA set up on your account)? Can you use git URLs instead of HTTPS URLs and SSH keys instead?

Comment: how can you push something from somewhere where there is no .git folder in? Are you in a git repository at all in your local machine?

Comment: there is .git folder (after init)

Answer (score 1):

To push an existing folder, make sure it is a git repository. If that is not the case, run `git init` in the folder. Then you may `git remote add origin <link to GitLab>` and finally `git push`. If upstream branch is not set, follow the instructions on CLI on how to setup the remote tracking branch.

Comment: I tried, and same results. the remote was set after git init. but same reults

Comment: it can't be. either git init prompted error because it was already a git repo, or it didn't, and then you'll have to create your first commit. Judging from your previous comment under your question, you were trying to push something that wasn't a git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the remote with ssh and not http:

```
git remote add origin git@...
```